# Unable to use Go get properly

Tags: go

I am a new user to go and I am trying this command.

```
go get github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go
```

And I am getting this error

```
package github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go
    imports github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go
    imports github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go: cannot find package "github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go (from $GOROOT)
    /home/arafat/go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go (from $GOPATH)
```

I know this seems to be a trivial issue but I am stuck at it.

Comment: the address is not found. Open it your browser and you will see. https://github.com/tensorflow/. I managed to get there: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib but did not found a go subfolder.

Comment: Maybe because of the branch https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/go/tensorflow/contrib/go

Comment: Also the error message seems really weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code to compile and install is *not* in the `master` branch (checked out by default by the `go get`), but [only in the `go` branch of that repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/go/tensorflow/contrib/go), try and:

```
cd $GOPATH/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
git checkout go
```

Then try again the compilation.

Comment: I am getting the error
`can't load package: package github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go: /home/arafat/go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go/lib.go: malformed #cgo argument: -I${SRCDIR}/../../../`

Comment: @ArafatK That is different. Now it finds the package, which was the initial question. Ie `go get` works. Let me check if there are any additional step in order to enable the compilation.

Comment: @ArafatK I didn't see any issue on that error message in the GitHub repo. Maybe SRCDIR is not correctly set?

Comment: I am not sure how to resolve that can you please elaborate. It would be a great help.

Comment: @ArafatK I am not sure either: I was answering your original question. You could ask a new one, with that new error message more visible.

Comment: I posted a new question

Comment: @ArafatK OK. Don't forget to mark this one as resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer