# Error on using Go get

Tags: git, go

After managing to `go get` the [tensorflow repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/) ([as described in my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760199/unable-to-use-go-get-properly/37760303?noredirect=1#comment62989984_37760303)).

I now have the right code in `$GOPATH` (the [one from the go branch](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/go/tensorflow/contrib/go)), but the compilation now generates the error message:

```
can't load package: 
package github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go:
/home/arafat/go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go/lib.g‌​o: 
malformed #cgo argument: -I${SRCDIR}/../../../
```

How can I solve this compilation issue?

Comment: Hello, You can continue on your first question. You don't need to ask an another one!

Comment: I am new to this website and I was told to ask a new question by the person who answered my previous question. At Least read the question and answer before downvoting.

Comment: @VonC I think the error has something to do with the flags here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/go/tensorflow/contrib/go/lib.go

Comment: When I changed -I${SRCDIR}/../../../  to  -I "/home/arafat/go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow". That is the actual location of the place The error changed to `
In file included from ../../../../go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go/tf_session_helper.cc:20:0:
../../../../go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go/tf_session_helper.h:22:49: fatal error: tensorflow/core/public/tensor_c_api.h: No such file or directory
 #include "tensorflow/core/public/tensor_c_api.h"
                                                 ^
compilation terminated.
`

Comment: I think I am not really able to make the flag directory work properly.

Comment: Updated your version of go first, so that you can at least use the SRCDIR variable.

Comment: I updated to go 1.4 and the same problem still persisted.

Comment: @ArafatK Go1.4 is not supported for this. Go1.6.2 is the current version. Go1.7 is coming soon.